# Data Exchange Connector ApplicationRegistry error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am having issues using the data exchange connector in Revit 2023 and get the error in the screenshot below. I'm using the Revit basic sample project with no modifications.

"Revit encountered a The type initializer for 'ConnectorViewModels.ApplicationRegistry' threw an exception."

[image]